# What type of scraping method to use for boots.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have successfully used the 2 script examples shown below on a number of websites without issue.

- **Script 1**: requests_html
- **Script 2**: BeautifulSoup

The scripts simply scrapes the product title.

However, when i use it for **boots.com** it returns **no results**.

I would appreciate if you could provide a working example showing how to scrape the product title so that I can understand the technology.

## Script 1: requests_html

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url ='https://www.boots.com/sensodyne-whitening-repair-and-protect-toothpaste-75ml-10143591'

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=1)

# print product title
product = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="estore_product_title"]/h1"]', first=True).text.strip()
print('Product:', product)
```

## Script 2: BeautifulSoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession # new

url = 'https://www.boots.com/sensodyne-whitening-repair-and-protect-toothpaste-75ml-10143591'

requests = HTMLSession()
r = requests.get(url)

# show 200 status code
print('Status Code:', r.status_code)

# print page contents
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)

# Print Page Title
page_title = soup.find('h1').text.strip()
print('Page Title:', page_title)
```

Comment: What details do you want from the website and for which products do you want it.?

Comment: Hi Ananth,

**Sample URLs:**  
https://www.boots.com/sensodyne-whitening-repair-and-protect-toothpaste-75ml-10143591  
https://www.boots.com/philips-sonicare-optimal-white-brushheads-hx6064-12-4pk-white-10253433  

**Details Required:**  
Product Title: Sensodyne Sensitive Toothpaste Repair & Protect Whitening 75ml  
Price: £5.50  
Offer: 2 for £8 on selected Sensodyne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output by just getting the class name and the tag in which it is present. Find those in the `Inspect Element` tab or source code.

```
page_title = soup.find('h1').text.strip()
price=  soup.find('div', class_="price price_redesign").text
offer = soup.find('li', class_="pdp-promotion-redesign").text
print('Page Title:', page_title)
print('Price:', price)
print('Offer:', offer)
```

This should give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the script. It worked as expected. 

Strange thing is that both my script and yours is similar. 
However, I noticed that when running in VSCode using a terminal command line it produced blank results. 
When clicking the triangle play button it ran the script producing the desired results. 
I now need to figure out why VSCode is behaving this way.